# pan 3D model using libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, pan

I am trying to pan a 3d object but it does not seem to work. I make a swipe gesture towards the left and right to pan the object along the x-axis. I have added a `Log` statement and that clearly shows me the pan values in the logcat but still the object doesnt move.

Here is my code

```
public class 3DTest implements ApplicationListener, GestureListener {

public ModelBatch modelBatch;
public Model model;
public ModelInstance instance;
public Environment environment;
public OrthographicCamera camera;
public CameraInputController camController;
public PerspectiveCamera cam;
public ModelLoader loader;

@Override
public void create() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    InputMultiplexer im = new InputMultiplexer();
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();

    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1280, 720);

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(1f, 1f, 1f);
    cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
    cam.near = 0.1f;
    cam.far = 300f;
    cam.update();

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);

    loader = new ObjLoader();
    model = loader.loadModel(Gdx.files.internal("data/cube.obj"));
    instance = new ModelInstance(model);
    im.addProcessor(new GestureDetector(this));
    im.addProcessor(camController);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(im);

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    modelBatch.dispose();
    model.dispose();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void render() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camController.update();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);    

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean fling(float arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean longPress(float arg0, float arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pan(float arg0, float arg1, float arg2, float arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("App","pan" +arg2);
    camera.translate(arg2, 0);
    camera.update();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean panStop(float arg0, float arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pinch(Vector2 arg0, Vector2 arg1, Vector2 arg2, Vector2 arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean tap(float arg0, float arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(float arg0, float arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean zoom(float arg0, float arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: You're panning your orthographic camera but you're rendering your modelbatch using your perspective camera.  That would explain why your view isn't changing

Comment: I tried panning and rendering using the same camera as well but still the object doesn't move :(

Comment: Why are you telling, that you want to pan the 3D object, but you're translating the camera instead?

Comment: @TheWhiteLlama: that's wrong I know but I tried all possible ways..My main task is to pan the 3d object but I am confused how to do it. Should I do something with the camera? or should I do something in the pan method...Please help I am new to libgdx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cam.position.set(1f, 1f, -10f);
```

Change your "z" (the third parameter) in `cam`.

It works fine.

Comment: I added that line...in the pan method what should I write?

Comment: @ParthDoshi in create() just change your this line cam.position.set(1f,1f,1f); to cam.position.set(1f,1f,-10f);

Comment: replace what? I replaced cam.position.set(1f,1f,1f) with cam.position.set(1f,1f,-10f)..do I now need to change anything inside pan method?

Comment: what about the code inside the pan method? Do i need to change that or any other line in the rest of my code. Please help! thanks

Comment: but at present its translating the camera in X direction..is that fine? `cam.translate(arg2,0,0) ?

Comment: Also, when I run the app now and try to pan, the object just disappears :(

Comment: yes, that's fine... presently it is rotating your cube in x,y,z directions accordingly with pan() values

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47442/discussion-between-parth-doshi-and-whitefang)